# *ngIf is not working to show the template if the array is empty

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OSgj.png)Hi I am new to angular and i have a problem with ngIf not working as expected in the tutorial. I have put the code snippits below. Any help with wold be very helpfull.

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { templateJitUrl } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.scss']
})

export class PostListComponent{

  posts = [];

}
```

Template file is this

```
 <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf='posts.length > 0'>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{ post.title }}
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description>
      {{ post.content }}
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p *ngIf='posts.length <= 0' > No posts added yet </p>
```

The error is returning posts.title and posts.contnet does not exist on type 'never'.

But when i the posts array as

```
  posts = [
    {title: 'First Post', content: 'First post contnet'},
    { title: 'Second Post', content: 'Secnd post contnet' },

  ];


//  posts = [];

}
```

Any help woudl be really appriciated.

Comment: Is this all the code? I would expect it to work.

Comment: Are you updating `posts` immutably? Meaning you're not using `.push`?

Comment: @AliF50 basikly i had it like this 
`
 posts = [
    {title: 'First Post', content: 'First post contnet'},
    { title: 'Second Post', content: 'Secnd post contnet' },

  ];


//  posts = []; `

So when i have one using i comented the other array

Comment: More data about the error please. Is this a compile or run time error? I suspect it may be a compile time and these are linting issues related to type declaration.

Comment: @E.Maggini Thank you for the comment I have attached a image of the error message

Comment: @GaëlJ same here this is the tutorial im following 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tRLveSyNz8&t=2952s the time stamp is 1:47:35

Answer (score 0):

Hi All thank you for helping I managed to fix the issue by typing the variable:

```
posts: any[] = [];
```

Comment: really should be `post:any[]=[]` to indicate that is an array of object

Comment: It should even be `post: SomeInterface[] = []` where you define `SomeInterface`. The power of TypeScript is in its type system.